# Can't fetch result

Tags: java, methods

I tried a simple program to check the equality of two numbers. I defined two methods. First one to get the numbers and the second one to check for equality. I first method is working well fetching the numbers but the other method is yielding nothing. Like if I enter 55 and 55, I should get `Numbers are equal` instead I get nothing. Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Check {

int first;
int second;
String C;

public void get(){
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number : ");
    first = S.nextInt();

    Scanner P  = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the second number : ");
    second = P.nextInt();
}



public String check(){

    if (first>second)
    {
        C = "First number is greater";
    }

    if (first<second)
    {
        C = "Second number is greater";
    }

    if (first==second)
    {
        C = "Numbers are equal";
    }
    return C;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Check obj = new Check();
    obj.get();
    obj.check();

}

}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you print `C` or the result of `check()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the `String` value,but as there are no statements to `print` in the main() method so the value gets un-utilised!

Store the output of `obj.check()` in some String object and display it in the main method.It'll work fine!

Like as :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Check obj = new Check();
obj.get();
String s=obj.check();
System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Also,any other doubt,you can ask unhesitatingly! I'll try to solve how much I can...

Answer (score 0):

You're discarding the return value. Do something with it

```
String value = obj.check();
```

Maybe print it

```
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.out.println(obj.check());` instead of just  `obj.check();`. Because this way, you don't use what returned from the check method.

Off topic: in get() method you don't have to define two different scanner objects. You can use

```
public void get(){
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number : ");
    first = S.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the second number : ");
    second = S.nextInt();
}
```

otherwise it's just a waste of memory.